# QML Change Size of Dropitem on Drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, qml, resize

I want to change the size of a Rectangle in the QML drag and drop example on drop to the size of the drop area. But somehow the Rectangle will not render to the new size although it takes the width and height values.

DragTile.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item
{
    id: rootItem
    property int boxWidth: 0
    property int boxHeight: 0
    property Item dragParent    

    width: boxWidth
    height: boxHeight   

    MouseArea
    {        
        id: mouseArea
        width: rootItem.boxWidth
        height: rootItem.boxHeight

        drag.target: msgTile

        onReleased:
        {
            parent = msgTile.Drag.target !== null ? msgTile.Drag.target : rootItem
            rootItem.boxHeight = parent.boxHeight
            rootItem.boxWidth = parent.boxWidth             
        }

        Rectangle
        {            
            id: msgTile

            color: "cyan"

            width: mouseArea.width
            height: mouseArea.height
          
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

            Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active
            Drag.hotSpot.x: width / 2
            Drag.hotSpot.y: height / 2


            //draging
            states: State
            {
                when: mouseArea.drag.active
                ParentChange { target: msgTile; parent: dragParent } // draw on top while draging
                AnchorChanges { target: msgTile; anchors.verticalCenter: undefined; anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The dragsource as well as the droparea take the size of a parent rectangle

in Main.qml

```
    Rectangle
    {
        x: 100
        y: 100

        width: 100
        height: 300

        border.width: 1

        DragSource
        {
            msgCount: 2
            msgCapacity: 10
            dragParent: topItem
        }

    }

    Rectangle
    {
        x: 400
        y: 100

        width: 150
        height: 300

        border.width: 1

        MsgDrop
        {
            msgCapacity: 12
        }
    }
```

The size of the droparea is a little bit larger, than the size of the dragtiles

Is there any order of rendering that I am missing?
I would be very happy for some advice.

Best regards

Comment: In your `onReleased` handler, you have this line: `rootItem.boxHeight = parent.boxHeight`  What do you think `parent` refers to there?

Comment: the parent refers to a `DropArea` which has a different width and hieght than the Rectangle